# Distinctive vs Distinguishing

Tags: meaning, differences

Is there a difference between the two words when used for saying “that which distinguishes (something) from others”?

For example

*… the distinctive patterns on the skin …*

or

*… the distinguishing patterns on the skin …*

I somehow find distinctive more fitting here, or that might be because of my own bias as I have mostly read distinguishing with “achievements” and such words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Distinct* means *clear*, so *distinctive* means *having the quality of clarity, easily recognised for what it is*.

*To distinguish* means to *tell apart, to identify*. A distinguishing mark heps one to discriminate between two individuals of similar type.

The insignia of a car might be distinctive and easily recognised, but it is the number plates that are the distinguishing marks.

Answer (score 6):

*Distinctive patterns* would be something you would especially notice, while *distinguishing patterns* would be ones used to tell one from the other.

These need not be altogether different, non-overlapping senses.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are correct that, in the example you gave, **distinctive** is the preferred form. Here **distinctive** is an adjective that reflects a quality that can separate the object from others, and often communicates an implied "very".

*His full body tattoos were distinctive.*

**Distinguishing** is used more often as a verb form.  While the participle **distinguishing** can connote that the object is capable of being differentiated from others, it seems less common and probably conveys a difference that is less than something which is distinctive.

*There were distinguishing indicators in the various test results which allowed differential diagnosis.*

Interestingly, the adjective **distinguished**, which derives from the verb **distinguish** almost always conveys a difference from other objects that is highly regarded.

*I yield the floor to the distinguished gentleman from Kentucky.* [Perhaps sarcastically.]

Answer (score 1):

"Distinctive" expresses uniqueness and has positive connotations.

"Distinguishing" is a neutral term describing a property which allows an object to be differentiated from other objects of like type.

Answer (score 0):

*Distinctive* is much more fitting here. I think *distinguish* would be a much higher degree of difference between two.

Comment: That's not the difference between the two statements.